# std::enable_if with std::is_same refuses to compile

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code fails to compile

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <fftw3.h>

template<class Real>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(Real* x, size_t length,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, Real>::value>::type* = nullptr)
    {
        y = fftw_alloc_real(length);
        fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(length, x, y, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute_r2r(plan, x, y);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    }

    foo(Real* x, size_t length,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<float, Real>::value>::type* = nullptr)
    {
        y = fftwf_alloc_real(length);
        fftwf_plan plan = fftwf_plan_r2r_1d(length, x, y, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftwf_execute_r2r(plan, x, y);
        fftwf_destroy_plan(plan); 
    }


private:
    Real* y;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x{12, 83, 96.3};
    foo<double> fd(x.data(), x.length());

    std::vector<float> xf{12, 82, 96.2};
    foo<float> ff(x.data(), x.length());
}
```

giving error message

```
test.cpp:14:33: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<float, Real>::value>::type* = nullptr)
```

What is wrong with my syntax or understanding of `std::enable_if` that makes this not compile? What is the fix so that I can use a template which still calls non-templated code from FFTW?

Comment: This is not how you do SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why?

Comment: Because substitution only applies to template parameters. Your two c'tors aren't templates. They both need to be well-formed when the template is instantiated.

Comment: So it would work if the class wasn't a template, and each constructor was?

Comment: @user14717 Yes, but do you really needs this here? Why not using `std::numeric_limits` to obtain the same information without having to have two different constructors?

Comment: @user14717 The constructors have to be templates. Whether they're inside a class or a class template is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holt: I don't need this code at all. It's representative of a much more complicated object which is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @user14717 Then you should add relevant code - Using SFINAE to initialise a member variables with different values is pointless, and it will be hard for us to provide relevant answer if you don't provide sufficient context.

Comment: @Holt: This has been done.

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk it through from the compiler's point of view. When you say `foo<double>`, you are instantiating the template `foo` with `Real = double`.

When we encounter the first constructor, we evaluate the `enable_if`, and find that `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, Real>::value>::type` is `void` (since `std::is_same<double, double>::value == true`). All is fine.

When we encounter the second constructor, we again try to instantiate it by evaluating the `enable_if`. However, this time `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<float, Real>::value>::type` does not exist, since `std::is_same<float, double>::value == false`. This is an error.

---

Any time you try to instantiate a `foo`, at least one of these two constructors will be ill-formed. If you wanted SFINAE to kick in, the constructors would need to be templated:

```
template<class Real>
class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    foo(T x,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type* = nullptr)
    {
        mantissa_bits = 52;
    }

    template <typename T>
    foo(T x,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<float, T>::value>::type* = nullptr)
    {
        mantissa_bits = 23;
    }


private:
    size_t mantissa_bits;
};
```

Although I've normally seen SFINAE-capable constructors look like this:

```
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    foo(T x)
    {
        mantissa_bits = 52;
    }
```